# Regex to capture series of 5digit numbers from a multi line string in python

Tags: python-3.x

**This is the command output1:**
Refresh Epoch 14
65041 65000 65062 65496 65489 65496 65489 4200000089
192.168.1.2 (via vrf office) from 10.254.233.3 (10.133.1.3)

**This is the command output2:**
Refresh Epoch 14
65041 65000 65062 65496 65489 65480
192.168.1.2 (via vrf office) from 10.254.233.3 (10.133.1.3)

You may get the output in two different way as given above.
I need to capture only 5 digits numbers only

if command1 output need to capture: "65041 65000 65062 65496 65489 65496 65489"
if I get command2 output need to capture: 65041 65000 65062 65496 65489 65480

```
import re
cmd_result = '''Refresh Epoch 14
  65041 65000 65062 65496 65489 65480
    192.168.1.2 (via vrf office) from 10.254.233.3 (10.133.1.3)'''

as_value = re.search('(\d{5} )+',cmd_result,re.M)
print(as_value)
<re.Match object; span=(188, 224), match='65041 65000 65062 65496 65489 '>
```

Comment: Is the last line the output?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the match content with `.group(0)`:

```
import re
o1 = "Refresh Epoch 14 65041 65000 65062 65496 65489 65496 65489 4200000089 192.168.1.2 (via vrf office) from 10.254.233.3 (10.133.1.3)"
o2 = "Refresh Epoch 14 65041 65000 65062 65496 65489 65480 192.168.1.2 (via vrf office) from 10.254.233.3 (10.133.1.3)"

pat = re.compile(r'(\d{5}[\s$])+', re.M)
def capt_digits(s):
    return re.search(pat, s).group(0)

print(capt_digits(o1))
print(capt_digits(o2))
```